# Adding subtitles for multiple mkv files by MKVmerge using terminal

Tags: bash, video-editing

I'm trying to adding subtitles for multiple mkv files. I use this script for doing this :

```
for file in *.mkv; do "/Applications/Mkvtoolnix-7.0.0.app/Contents/MacOS/mkvmerge" -o "${file%\.*}(1).mkv"   "(" "$file" ")"  "(" "${file%\.*}.srt" ")" ; rm $file
```

It work fine for root directory only. But it don't work for all files in subfolder , please help me to make it work for all files in subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```bash
# make bash function to do conversion and deletion
conv() {
 /Applications/Mkvtoolnix-7.0.0.app/Contents/MacOS/mkvmerge -o "${1%\.*}(1).mkv"   "(" "$1" ")"  "(" "${1%\.*}.srt" ")"
 rm "${1}"
}
# make conv function available to xargs
export -f conv
# recursively convert every .mkv file in current directory
find . -name "*.mkv" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I% bash -c 'conv "$@"' _ %
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bash`, do

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.mkv
do
    (your MKVmerge, etc., commands)
done
```

Setting the `globstar` shell option tells `bash` to expand `**/` as all directories and subdirectories.

P.S. Always quote all shell variable references
(unless you have a very good reason not to, and you're sure you know what you're doing). 
In particular, say `rm "$file"` instead of `rm $file`.